# Evaluating $ \lim_{ x \to 1} \frac{\int_{1}^{x}\ln^2(t) dt}{(x-1)^3} $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

When I try to do it ,

$ \lim \limits_{ x \to 1}  \frac{\int_{1}^{x}\ln^2(t) dt}{(x-1)^3}=\lim \limits_{ x \to 1}  \frac{\ln^2(x)}{(x-1)^3} = \lim \limits_{ x \to 1}  \frac{2\ln(x)}{3x(x-1)^2}=  \lim \limits_{ x \to 1}  \frac{2}{3x(2x(x-1)+(x-1)^2)}  $ = $\frac{2}{0} = \infty$
(given three uses of L'Hopital).

I checked through an online computing website and the answer should be $\frac {1}{3}$.

I would love to get some help on my math and when deriving a definite integral, is there any importance to the $a$ and $b$ in $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)$ ?

Assuming I had $2$ as for $a$ in my equation for example , would that have any effect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the evaluation of the limit: applying L'Hôpital's rule once forms

$$ \lim_{ x \to 1} \frac{\int_{1}^{x}\ln^2(t) \,dt}{(x-1)^3} = \lim_{ x \to 1}\frac{\ln^2(x)}{3(x-1)^2},$$

where the chain rule implies that the derivative of the denominator is

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x-1)^3\right]=3(x-1)^2.$$

From here you can apply L'Hôpital's rule two more times to find

$$ \lim_{ x \to 1}\frac{\ln^2(x)}{3(x-1)^2}=\lim_{ x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x)}{3x(x-1)}=\lim_{ x \to 1}\frac{1}{x(6x-3)}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

To answer your second question, the result follows from the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). Let $f$ be a continuous, real-valued function defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Suppose $F$ is defined for all $x\in[a,b]$ by

$$F(x)=\int_a^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt.$$

Then

$$F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{g(x)}f(t) \,dt=f(g(x))g'(x).$$

In your problem we are given $f(t)=\ln^2(t)$ (which is continuous over the positive real numbers) with the integration constant $a=1$. Therefore the fundamental theorem of calculus implies

$$F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{x}\ln^2(t) \,dt=\ln^2(x).$$

Note that we could change the lower integration constant to any other positive real constant $a>0$ (as the fundamental theorem of calculus would still hold) to deduce

$$F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}\ln^2(t) \,dt=\ln^2(x).$$

However, if the upper limit of integration was $x^2$ instead of $x$, then we would find

$$F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x^2}\ln^2(t) \,dt=2x\ln^2(x^2).$$

Comment: Appreciate the effort , very well detailed and understandable  response . Thank you !

Comment: Just a followup question if I may , assuming $b$ would have been $x^2$ would I need to derive the $b$ as well and multiply by the answer ? (Because according to the fundamental theorem of calculus it’s not mentioned) @Axion004

Comment: @Losh_EE: I updated my answer per your comments. If either of the answers resolves your question, feel free to close out the question by accepting one of the answers (or upvoting the answer if it is helpful).

Comment: Definitely , I can't upvote yet but I have chosen your answer . It's very well written and answers the 2 questions I had . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When applying l'hospital, why didn't you derive $\left(x-1\right)^3$, that'd make de $1/3$ appear ?

It'd give

$$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{\ln^2\left(x\right)}{3\left(x-1\right)^2}
$$

Comment: Thank You Sir , May I ask  If I have had $\lim \limits_{ x \to 1}  \frac{\int_{2}^{x}ln^2(t) dt}{(x-1)^3}$ would that make the Equation After $l'hospital$ equal to $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{\ln^2\left(x\right)-ln^2(2)}{3\left(x-1\right)^2}$ ?( My second Question above )

Comment: In this case the expression is not zero by zero but non zero by zero and hence infinite.

Comment: It wouldnt as the derivative of $x \mapsto \int_{a}^{x}\ln^2\left(t\right)\text{d}t$ is $\ln^2\left(x\right)$ no matter what's $a$

Comment: We require $a>0$ as the domain of $f(t)=\ln^2(t)$ is all real $t>0$.